# How to run Python test case with Appium?

Tags: python, ios, pycharm, appium, appium-ios

I've created simple test case using Python (in PyCharm editor) which should click on Join/Login button on iOS app, but it doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
from appium import webdriver
import unittest
import os


class LoginTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        desired_caps = {}
        desired_caps['platformName'] = 'iOS'
        desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '11.0'
        desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'iPhone Simulator' # Run on simulator
        desired_caps['bundleId'] = 'com.matchbook.MatchbookApp'
        desired_caps['app'] = os.path.abspath('/Users/majdukovic/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MatchBook-bgvchkbwrithuaegnjgpoffewdag/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MatchBook.app') # Path to .app
        self.wd = webdriver.Remote('http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
        self.wd.implicitly_wait(60)
        loginButton = self.wd.find_element_by_id("JOIN/LOGIN") # Button ID
        self.assertTrue(loginButton.is_displayed())
        loginButton.click()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(LoginTests)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

If I run this test case it returns:
"Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK"

Appium server is already running and app is opened. In PyCharm Preferences I've selected py.test as default test runner.

**Details of my setup:**
macOS - HighSierra v10.13
Appium desktop app - v1.2.6
Python - v2.7.10
xCode - v9.0.1
Simulator - iPhone 8, iOS v11.0

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: so, it is like nothing is happening. I run my test and this is message I get: ""Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK"". I can't see anything in appium logs or that button is clicked, it's like this code does nothing, I'm not sure if there are any preferences I should set in PyCharm or code is not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure what is the problem, I tried a lot of things, but it won't work from Pycharm , so I've written code in Atom editor and run it from Terminal with command:
    "python -m py.test name_of_test.py -s" and it works.

Answer (score 0):

How about simple code like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Met the same issue. Found out, that "`setUp`" name is not reads as "`test`"case.
try this:

```
def test_testcase1(self):
```

Testcases should be named like "`test_*testcasename_or_whatever*(self)`"

Answer (score 0):

File name should be test*.py , For example:

```
test1.py
```

Function name should be test*, For example:

```
def test_testcase1(self):
```